# Jboss server startup exception

Tags: java, jboss

I am seeing the following exception while starting Jboss-4.0.3SP1 on my Windows 7 64 bit machine. I am researching on this to see if there any clash for the ports etc.. Any thoughts from you would be appreciated!

```
14:52:13,067 WARN  [ServiceController] Problem starting service jboss:service=invoker,type=pooled
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:359)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:319)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:185)
        at org.jboss.invocation.pooled.server.PooledInvoker.startService(PooledInvoker.java:205)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalStart(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:274)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalLifecycle(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:230)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController$ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceController.java:943)
        at $Proxy0.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:428)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:446)
        at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:446)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:72)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
        at $Proxy4.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer.start(SARDeployer.java:285)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.start(MainDeployer.java:989)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:790)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:753)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:737)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
        at $Proxy5.deploy(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.doStart(ServerImpl.java:453)
        at org.jboss.system.server.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:330)
        at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:187)
        at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:438)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show the command you're using to invoke JBoss, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! Fixed the issue, one of the port was in use.

```
<attribute name="ServerBindPort">4445</attribute>
```

4445 was in use, so changed to 4446

File name : **jboss-4.0.3SP1\server\default\conf\jboss-service.xml**

netstat was useful to identify the port

```
netstat -an |find /i "4445"
```

TCP    0.0.0.0:4445           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Answer (score 1):

Most likely port conflict. Check list of ports open on your computer with 'netstat' command for example.

Answer (score 1):

Check for whether any of these ports are already running on your machine with the `netstat` command: 1098, 1099 4444, 4445, 8009, 8080, 8083, 8093. Most likely port 8080 is already running on your machine but check for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Some times,it might be due to firewall service.

Its also better to try changing port number in server.xml, which is found in \server\default\deploy\jbossweb-tomcat55.sar